# How to get 08:00 of this String 2015-01-01T08:00:00-02:00

Tags: java

```
 String date = "2015-01-01T08:00:00-02:00";
```

and I need get only 08:00

Can you please help to parser this formate?

I tried this code below. but not work

```
 try {
        String[] buffer = null;
        buffer = dateString.split("T");

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        return dateFormat.parse(buffer[0]);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you already tried something? Done some research?

Comment: How about `date.substring(11, 16)`?

Comment: I put my code in question

Comment: I suggest you use a date format which matches the format you are using. Why are you parsing the date if you want the time?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8)

```
String date = "2015-01-01T08:00:00-02:00";
ZonedDateTime ldt = ZonedDateTime.parse(date);
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
System.out.println(dtf.format(ldt)); // 08:00
// Thank @MadProgrammer for the following ones. :)
System.out.println(ldt.toLocalTime()); // Also prints 08:00
System.out.println(ldt.getHour()+":"+ldg.getMinute()); // Prints 8:0 but you could use 
                                                       // those variable for other things 
                                                       // if you do not need to print them
```

Comment: And/or use `ldt.getHour()` and `ldt.getMinute()` if you'd prefer the actual values for some meaning for use or `ldt.toLocalTime()` to perform comparisons

Comment: @MadProgrammerThank you, I'll add those possibilities too.

Comment: @MadProgrammer ldt.getHour will trim the extra 0's and give the following output : `8:0`

Comment: Yes, but if you are trying to test to see if it's 830, having the hour a minute as separate variables will be more useful.  We only know that the OP wants the time part, we don't know why, so while I accept your answer as been a viable solution, suggesting some other options can't help ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to Convert this to [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) object and then you can get what ever you want from it.

```
String dateInString = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd/MM/yyyy/hh:mm:ss")
        .format(cal.getTime())
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd/MM/yyyy/hh:mm:ss");
Date parsedDate = formatter.parse(dateInString);
```

Use this date to set it in Calendar. You could use the date object it self but it deprecated https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
  String date = "2015-01-01T08:00:00-02:00";

  try{
       String[] buffer = null;
       buffer = horaInicio.split("T");
       DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
       dateFormat.parse(buffer[1]);

     }catch (Exception e) {
       Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
     }
```